# open flash player and test swf from textmate

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, terminal, textmate, textmatebundles

i usually write my code with textmate.

a custom command for testing the proj directly in flash is:

```
echo 'document.testMovie();' > /tmp/fc.jsfl
open -a /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ CS5/Adobe\ Flash\ CS5.app /tmp/fc.jsfl
```

what about the flash standalone player?

```
echo 'document.testMovie();' > /tmp/fc.jsfl
open -a /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4/player/mac/Flash\ Player.app /tmp/fc.jsfl
```

works great but it only open the player...it doesn'pass the file to it.
can you help me?

thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the Flahs Player like that, you need to pass it a swf, not a jsfl file, so you need to compile the code first.

Have a look at this neat [tutorial](http://jaapvandermeer.com/2010/03/01/textmatefcsh-compile-flex-in-textmate-using-fcsh/) on setting up TextMate with the Flex Shell Compiler.

Also you might like [Project Sprouts](http://projectsprouts.org/screencasts.html), check it out!

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the standalone Flash Player can run JSFL files.

To quote Adobe, "The Flash JavaScript application programming interface (JavaScript API) is a complementary programming tool that lets you create scripts that run in the authoring environment."

"document.testMovie();" is a command that tells the Flash IDE to test the currently active document, to do the same as if you would select "Test Movie" from the "Control" menu in the IDE.

You could probably set something up to run a swf file in the standalone Flash Player, but it would need to be compiled first.